# Rewriting my scores text file to make sure it only has the Last 4 scores (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

Previously, I had - with the help of SO users - been able to find how to store a maximum of 4 keys inside a Python Document with the maxlength property inside the dictionary.

Now, I want to go further. Below is a text file with all the **recent** scores of my participants - Dave, Jack and Adam.

```
Jack:10
Dave:20
Adam:30
Jack:40
Adam:50
Dave:60
Jack:70
Dave:80
Jack:90
Jack:100
Dave:110
Dave:120
Adam:130
Adam:140
Adam:150
```

Now, here is my code that lets me see the last 4 Scores in Python:

```
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
scores_guessed = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.deque(maxlen=4))
with open('Guess Scores.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
    name,val = line.split(":")
    scores_guessed[name].appendleft(int(val))

for k in sorted(scores_guessed):
    print("\n"+k," ".join(map(str,scores_guessed[k])))

writer = open('Guess Scores.txt', 'wb')

for key, value in scores_guessed.items():
   writer.writerow([key,':',value])
```

Clearly, it will print out the following result for the dictionary:

```
Adam 150 140 130 50

Dave 120 110 80 60

Jack 100 90 70 40
```

**However**, I want the file to read me the last four results in alphabetical order:

```
Adam:150
Adam:140
Adam:130
Adam:50
Dave:120
Dave:110
Dave:80
Dave:60
Jack:100
Jack:90
Jack:70
Jack:40
```

I thought that this block of code would work:

```
for key, value in scores_guessed.items():
   writer.writerow([key,':',value])
```

Yet this returns me the result:

```
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'writerow'
```

For instance, if adam got a score of 200, I want the scores_guessed to be rewritten as:

```
Adam:200
Adam:150
Adam:140
Adam:130
```

What is going wrong?

**UPDATE** - In response to the first answer below, I have edited the last code block to this:

```
for key, value in scores_guessed.items():
    writer.write("{}:{}\n".format(key,value))
```

Yet it gives me this message:
    writer.write("{}:{}\n".format(key,value))
      TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

What is happening?

Comment: Instead of `writer.writerow(...)` do `writer.write('{}:{}\n'.format(key, value))`. Also I would change the name of that variable to something like `outfile` since, naming it `writer` is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `writer.writerow` syntax you use corresponds to [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer), which is used in the following way:

```
import csv
with open('some_file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    writer.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

It seems to me you are using some wrong reference to do this, since you are not using `csv` module in your code above.

So, alter your following code

```
for key, value in scores_guessed.items():
   writer.writerow([key,':',value])
```

to this code:

```
for key, value in scores_guessed.items():       
    output = "%s:%s\n" % (key,value)
    writer.write(output)
```

***Edit***

You are opening your file in binary mode, instead open it in text mode using

```
writer = open('Guess Scores.txt', 'wt')
for key, value in scores_guessed.items():       
    output = "{}:{}\n".format(key,value)
    writer.write(output)
writer.close()
```

***EDIT 2***

Since you use deque, use:

```
writer = open('Guess Scores.txt', 'wt')
for key, value in scores_guessed.items():       
    output = "{}:{}\n".format(key,','.join(map(str, scores_guessed[key])))
    writer.write(output)
writer.close()
```

Or use:

```
with open("output.txt", "wt") as f:
    for key in scores_guessed:
        f.write("{} {}".format(key, ','.join(map(str, scores_guessed[key]))))
```

Comment: Another error. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'`

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava which version of python are you using?

Comment: I will ask the question separately later as comments may not be suitable for other users that may be interested to a solution similar to mine.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava Check edits ... these work on my system ... took me  a while to go through the docs ..

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work - still gives me the first type error I received. Would it be possible if you could post all the code on gitHub or a similar code service because it does not at all on my computer. The dictionary prints perfectly but then it throws the error and also then leaves the .txt file empty since there is nothing that can be written due to the error itself holding the IDLE behind.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava You are using IDLE implies you are on Windows? In that case, try changing `writer = open('Guess Scores.txt', 'wb')` to some other name like `writer = open('Guess_Scores.txt', 'wb')`. If that doesn't work, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Nope, that does not work either. I will need to ask the question separately.

Comment: Apologies, but your code has made it much easier to get another solution when my 90 minute limit is finished.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava I think I finally figured it out, check edits.

Comment: Ok. There are no errors. BUT there is actually no text inside the new file. It is simply empty.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava So you are seeing the output from the print dict, but the output file is empty wihtout any errors? Are you sure you looking at the right output file, I have changed the file name, and added the `.close` statement..

Comment: ! Ok, fantastic. That works. One issue, it does return this odd line piece of code. `Dave:deque([120, 110, 80, 60], maxlen=4)
Adam:deque([150, 140, 130, 50], maxlen=4)
Jack:deque([100, 90, 70, 40], maxlen=4)
`

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava This one is simple, we are using deque so that it is getting printed as is, using map should correct that. Check edits, and don't forget to accept and upvote :)

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava Much appreciated man, I ended up parsing the documentation for file handling in python3 and learning new stuff, so the effort is (hopefully) worth it :)

Comment: But hey, how do I print each score on a separate line like the one I've been trying to get towards on my code? So I can read each one in alphabetical order?