# Python Overwrite Dictionary write to text file issue

Tags: python, dictionary, writer

In my last question [Rewriting my scores text file to make sure it only has the Last 4 scores (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507196/rewriting-my-scores-text-file-to-make-sure-it-only-has-the-last-4-scores-python/28507339?noredirect=1#comment45337484_28507339) I managed to get a dictionary to be printed out like this:

```
Adam 150 140 130 50

Dave 120 110 80 60

Jack 100 90 70 40
```

But I also wanted the dictionary to show the last 4 results in alphabetical order, as such:

```
Adam:150
Adam:140
Adam:130
Adam:50
Dave:120
Dave:110
Dave:80
Dave:60
Jack:100
Jack:90
Jack:70
Jack:40
```

I have tried to use `for k, v in d.iteritems():` but that does not work either since there are 4 values to every key in one dictionary (4 scores to every 1 name).

What is the fix to this solution to get the dictionary to print out the list like the block of text above back into my text file (guess_scores.txt)?

The code that helps me write the scores into the text file is this, if you require it.

```
writer = open('Guess Scores.txt', 'wt')

for key, value in scores_guessed.items():       
    output = "{}:{}\n".format(key,','.join(map(str, scores_guessed[key])))
    writer.write(output)
writer.close()
```

But I can't use the 3rd line (output = ... ) because that writes the scores to the text file similar to the block of code right at the top. I did try to use the iteritems but that returned an error in the IDLE.

Thanks, Delbert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d={'Adam': [150 ,140, 130 ,50] ,'Dave': [120, 110 ,80 ,60] ,'Jack' :[100, 90, 70 ,40]}
>>> for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
...    for item in v:
...      print str(k) + ":" + str(item)
... 
Adam:150
Adam:140
Adam:130
Adam:50
Dave:120
Dave:110
Dave:80
Dave:60
Jack:100
Jack:90
Jack:70
Jack:40
```

And for write in file :

```
with open('Guess Scores.txt', 'wt') as f :
      for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
          for item in v:
                 f.write(str(k) + ":" + str(item)+'\n')
```

Comment: Yes, the `zip` returns to me as an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava maybe you didn't write it correctly! can you show your error ?

Comment: Copied your exact block of code! `for k,v in d.items():
    print zip(repeat(k,len(v)),v)`

Comment: Where the print is indented into a new line.

Comment: `SyntaxError - Invalid Syntax` ... `zip` is highlighted in red.

Comment: Would you like me to link it as an image of some sort?

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava no, surely you have a bad copy or maybe you miss some things, anyway you dont need that , remove that part and see the result of writing in file!

Comment: OK, that works. But they all appear in one line. `Adam:150Adam:140Adam:130Dave:120Dave:110Dave:80Jack:100Jack:90Jack:70` how can it be put into separate lines?

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava oop, you need a new line! i fixed the answer! try that!

Comment: You are my new best friend! Thanks a million! @KasraAD

Comment: Why use `zip` and `repeat` at all? Wouldn't `for k,v in sorted(d.items()): for item in v: print k + ":" + item` have done the same thing?

Comment: @Kevin yead surely! i dont know my self that why in the world i have done that!!!! ;) some times we make mistake because of Simplicity!!!! thanks alot for reminding!